# How can I correct errors when connecting android phone the pi with a usb cable?

Tags: raspbian, usb, android

I have pi B+ with a new install of rasbian today

I am trying to connect my Samsung Galaxy Edge 6 with a usb cable. I have previously connected the phone to a linux pc using the same cable with no problems. I have tried this with two different cables.

I am following the instructions given [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=90728).

However, when I connect to the Pi it goes into a loop, creating error dialogs like the one shown in the image below.

[image]

The errors are created continuously as long as the phone is connected. Occasionally, I get a dialog similar to:

[image]

As the error refers to udev, I have check the udev directory and as each error dialog appears a file is created in dev/bus/usb/001, and then is deleted immediately.

The problem seems similar to the on described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643281/couldnt-find-matching-udev-devices) and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=520814) and so  I have installed mtp-tools and libmtp-runtime.

When I run lsusb with phone connected I don't get an entry.

[image]

Can anyone please help me to find a solution to my problem?

EDIT 20190107 =================================================

This is what I know so far:

I now have a brand new, raw and unmodified installation of Rasbian.

I have two android devices, an S6 phone and a Galaxy tablet. I have multiple cables and have tested both devices on both my Unix platform and my Pi.

```
                        S6 phone    Galaxy tablet
Unix both usb ports         Y           Y
Unix both usb cables        Y           Y
Pi   both usb ports         N           Y
Pi   both usb cables        N           Y

(Y=works, N=does not work)
```

So, for some reason the phone is 'seen' on the unix box, but not on the Pi

Comment: Would the person who gave a -1 for this question please explain why? You can see that I am a new contributor. I have no idea what is required in this sort of question. My internet searches for a solution have proved fruitless

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! The one you are asking why he had down voted will not see your comment. You have to address him with @Username ... But for me there is no other information than that you connected your mobile phone with an usb cord to the RasPi and that is has problems then. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here and how to ask to get best answers.  I have upvoted you for motivation ;-)

Comment: your question is not really an RPi question .... it is a linux question

Comment: @Ingo Thanks. I'll take your advice and revisit the question

Comment: @jsotola the Raspberry Pi has a problem, isn't it?

Comment: it appears to be a linux software issue ..... unless you have a USB port hardware failure, then it would  be an RPi problem ..... do other USB devices fail when plugged into the USB port?

Comment: @jsotola Other USB devices work on the same port. I have tried to connect the phone on on other ports

Comment: google "how to fix usb device not recognized raspberry pi" there are a lot of possibilities still and we can't run these tests for you.  for example you could fully charge the phone before attaching or try a powered hub, or use dmesg instead of staring at a dir or going for lsusb.  Can also check what it is recognized as on the other linux machine and make sure the same "driver" is on the pi.  if i had to guess i'd say power issue simply because it is a usb problem on a pi.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use USB tethering to connect to the internet with the mobile phone. The links you are used are completely outdated. They are four or five years old. If you followed that and configured `/etc/network/interfaces` then you are wrong. This isn't used with *Raspbian Stretch* anymore by default. It uses `dhcpcd`. Also installing `mtp-tools` and `libmtp-runtime` doesn't make sense under this conditions.

Raspbian Stretch is configured to work out of the box with USB tethering. I have just tested it with my installation of [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-11-13](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). The desktop version should also do. I connected my Samsung Galaxy with an USB cord to the Raspberry Pi and enabled `USB-Tethering` on the Galaxy in its submenu and it works. I can get into the Internet through the mobile phone.

Comment: I have just done a complete re-install of Rasbian, re booted and tried to connect the phone having made NO changes to the system at all. I still get the same message. Does this mean a problem with the phone?

Comment: @Psionman Seems to be. But I will look at the error. What have I to do to get the same error?

Comment: I have tried another android device on the Pi and it works fine. Must be a phone problem ;(

Comment: @Psionman Glad that you fixed it :-) If my answer helped you to find the solution it would be nice if you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side. This will finish the question and show other users that it has an answer.

Comment: Sorry. It's not fixed. I still need to be able to connect my phone and I cannot. I'm about to edit the question with a summary of my findings so far :)